# How does rsync script delete most of the files on my NAS?

Tags: linux, debian

So I was following [this tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-incremental-backups-using-rsync-on-linux) to backup my Debian instance

After running the script I noticed it was set to only backup the home dir. I wanted to backup everything in my root dir to a dir in my NAS. So I modified the script to look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# A script to perform incremental backups using rsync

set -o errexit
set -o nounset
set -o pipefail

readonly SOURCE_DIR="/"
readonly BACKUP_DIR="/link/to/my/nas/Server Backups"
readonly DATETIME="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')"
readonly BACKUP_PATH="${BACKUP_DIR}/${DATETIME}"
readonly EXCLUDE="/link/to/my/nas/
readonly LATEST_LINK="${BACKUP_DIR}/latest"

mkdir -p "${BACKUP_DIR}"

rsync -av --delete \
  "${SOURCE_DIR}/" \
  --link-dest "${LATEST_LINK}" \
  --exclude=".cache" \
  "${BACKUP_PATH}" \
  "${EXCLUDE}"

rm -rf "${LATEST_LINK}"
ln -s "${BACKUP_PATH}" "${LATEST_LINK}"
```

And it deleted almost everything on my NAS!! I'm assuming there's no way to undo this. Which isn't the end of the world because it's backed up. But what in the world happened here??? Why didn't it backup as expected and why did it delete anything besides the files under LATEST_LINK?

Logs from running the script:

```
root:/utils# ./backup-script.sh
sending incremental file list
rsync: [sender] link_stat "/link/to/my/nas/Server Backups/2023-01-07_15:58:36" failed: No such file or directory (2)
--link-dest arg does not exist: /link/to/my/nas/Server Backups/latest
^Crsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(713) [sender=3.2.7]
rsync error: received SIGUSR1 (code 19) at main.c(1613) [generator=3.2.7]
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `rsync` deletes whatever doesn't exists on the target that also doesn't exist on the source except for what is specified by `exclude` that exists within the target. For something like this, it's best to use the `--dry-run` switch so that what will happen is sent to stdout so that you can see what's gong on before actually running the command.

Comment: Is it because --exclude only picked up .cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to explain why rsync did something you weren't expecting.

Here's your command rewritten into canonical order so that command options are first and paths are at the end. This doesn't change the meaning but it helps explain the effect:

```
rsync
  -av                           # Archive mode, verbosely 
  --delete                      # Delete in destination if not in source
  --link-dest "$LATEST_LINK"    # Link unchanged files to a match by name
  --exclude ".cache"            # Exclude file/directory
  "$SOURCE_DIR/"                # Source 1
  "$BACKUP_PATH"                # Source 2
  "$EXCLUDE"                    # Destination
```

Clearly you meant to write `--exclude "${EXCLUDE}"` instead of just `"${EXCLUDE}"`. Unfortunately the effect of what you did write - and execute - was to delete everything under `$EXCLUDE` that wasn't present under either `$SOURCE_DIR` or `$BACKUP_PATH`.

Here's the command written correctly:

```
rsync                        \
  -av                        \
  --delete                   \
  --link-dest "$LATEST_LINK" \
  --exclude ".cache"         \
  --exclude "$EXCLUDE"       \
  "$SOURCE_DIR/"             \
  "$BACKUP_PATH"
```

It doesn't help now, but for future reference the `--dry-run` (`-n`) flag is well worth using if you're going to apply `--delete` or some other irretrievable action. I use it often!